# Show that $Y$ is the set of all isolated points in $(X, T(Y))$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and $Y⊂X$

Consider the topology $T(Y) = \{A| A ⊂ Y\} ∪ \{X\}$

i) Show that $Y$ is the set of all isolated points in $(X, T(Y))$

ii) Show that the closure of $Y$ is $X$

I'm having trouble understanding isolated points in topological spaces. I read that every proper subspace of X has empty interior. These are things I'm not seeing clearly. Any help would be useful.

Comment: (i) For a point $a\in Y$ there is an open set $\{a\}$ that contains it and no other point of $X$. (ii) This one is false if $Y=\emptyset$ and $X\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: For (ii) show that $X$ is closed, and any set $Z$ such that $Y\subseteq Z\subsetneq X$ is not closed (closed means the complement in X is open)

Comment: (ii')  If $Y\neq\emptyset$ and $F\supset Y$  is a closed set, then $X\setminus F$ is open. Since $X\setminus F\neq X$, then $X\setminus F\subset Y$ and also $X\setminus F\subset X\setminus Y$. Therefore $X\setminus F=\emptyset$. This means that $F=X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $Y$ is non-empty, as otherwise (ii) is false when $X$ is non-empty. So $Y \neq \emptyset$ in the remainder.

Suppose that $x \in X$. If $x \in Y$, $\{x\}$ is open as a subset of $Y$ so $x$ is isolated. If $x \notin Y$, the only open subset containing $x$ is $X$ itself (see definition) and this never equals $\{x\}$ alone, as $Y$ is non-empty. So $x$ is not isolated. So $x$ isolated iff $x\in Y$ which proves i).

(ii) can be done in several ways: as noted for all $x \in X\setminus Y$ we have that the only neighbourhood of $x$ is $X$ and this intersects $Y$ (as $Y$ is non-empty!). So all $x \in X\setminus Y$ are adherent (even limit) points of $Y$ and so $\overline{Y}=X$.

Or note that the closed sets of $X$ are the complements of the open sets, so either $\emptyset$ or $X\setminus A$ with $A \subseteq Y$. $Y$ is not subset of $\emptyset$ (it's non-empty!) and only a subset of $X\setminus A$ if $A=\emptyset$ (otherwise any $a \in A$ would be in $Y$ but not in $X\setminus A$), in which case we get $X$, which is thus the *only* closed set that contains $Y$ and so again $\overline{Y}=X$